# How do current ratings on barrel connectors work?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, high-current

I'm trying to power a pcb using a psu that is rated at 12V 10A and has a barrel connector with a jack that is 2.5mm x 5.5mm. I've tested my board with screw terminals and it draws about 8A. I want to make the design easier to connect and disconnect the power but I'm having a hard time finding barrel connectors that will work. I can't seem to find any barrel connectors that are rated at or above 10A for 12v dc.

On digikey they suggest http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PD-40V/CP-7440V-ND/2712203 as the connector for psus that supply up to 17A but it is only rated at 7.5A.

Am I misunderstanding how the current rates are listed or is there a special way to connect one of these high current dc psus to the board?

Thanks

Comment: I've seen these connectors used for power but for much lower currents... The digikey advise is wrong anyway, the manufacturer datasheet agrees with the 7.5A rating.

Comment: That isn't a "barrel" connector, it's a "DIN" connector. Barrel connectors have coaxial contacts.

Comment: Oxidation and contact resistance increases rapidly with temp. thus voltage drop increases with I^2R when hot.

Comment: Sorry I think I might have confused my question posting a link to that connector but the answer about it applying to 1 pin makes a lot of sense. I'm actually looking at a psu that would need this kind of terminal [link](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PJ-002BH-SMT-TR/CP-002BHPJTR-ND/404626). That says it is rated at 5A and 24V. Would it work at 10A 12V?

Comment: I can find psus that are rated to give 120W at 10A 12V with that connector but not any barrel connectors that are. I'm just curious how people normally connect those high current psus to a board with that kind of terminal.

Comment: The voltage drop across the connection (and hence the voltage used to calculate power dissipation) depends on the current through the connector, not on the voltage passed along the connection. That's why the voltage used doesn't factor into the maximum ratings until the dielectric strength is overcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connector you mention would work for your application as previously mentioned: two pins for positive and two for ground.  However, I would not recomend that type of connector for basic DC power as it would be difficult to attach to your wires/expensive.  Instead, try a connector such as Anderson Powerpole ([15A version](http://www.powerwerx.com/anderson-powerpoles/powerpole-sets/15-amp-red-black-anderson-powerpole-sets.html)), which comes in numerous different sizes for different current ratings and will allow easy crimping and mounting to a wire.

If you really do want a barrel plug (unlike that which you mentioned), one example is this guy ([datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/KC-300479.pdf), [mouser](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kobiconn/1710-2522/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtnOp%252bbbqA00%252brH%252bGhOEZAawr08LinZbeY=)) which can easily handle 20A.

Comment: The connector on mouser was the one I was looking for but I hadn't been able to find. It says it connects to the board through a wire mounting style but the datasheet doesn't seem very descriptive. Do you know if there would be a place to solder wire onto it and then run those wires to a screw terminal on the pcb? Thanks.

Comment: Most barrel jacks have solder lugs rather than crimps for attaching wires, so as long as you can solder you should be fine.

Comment: I was looking more at that one from mouser and it looks like it is a plug not a jack. Do you know if there are any jacks that can handle 10A at 12V in from a barrel connector dc plug? If there aren't, then what do those plugs plug into?

Comment: This jack should work for your purposes.  http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/449/KC-300075-202442.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Connector is rated at 7.5A, but you have 4 pins there.

I think this that current rating applies to 1 pin.

You can use 2 pins for positive, 2 pins for negative and you have 15A connector.